executing code only once after detecting a keypress in unity
I want to execute a function when detecting a Backspacetab in unity.
My Problem is that, although I have implemented a Timer to wait after my function hat been executed, it executes 32 times or until the List AllGamesMoves is empty, before waiting for the timer.
Why?
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Backspace))
        {
            ProcessBackspace();
        }
    }
    
    void ProcessBackspace()
    {
        if (timeUntilNextPress <= 0 && chessBoard.AllGamesMoves.Count > 0)
        {
            timeUntilNextPress = cooldown;
            Debug.Log("Activated");
            // my code ...
            
        }
        else
        {
            timeUntilNextPress -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

I have tryed a boolean flag, GetKeyUp, Thread.Sleep(1000) and more, but nothing seems to work.

32? so like 1 per chess peice perhaps? if it happens 32 times, while the logic has some flaws (such as timeuntilnextpress only decrements each frame you press the key for...) this code by itself is not the cause of 32 runnings..

you dont have to do all the timer things. just Input.GetKeyDown is enough and probably players cant press it more than once in 32 miliseconds. but your problem here is that you are doing the timeUntilNextPress -= Time.deltaTime; in the key down event which isnt correct. you have to do it in the update. or better, just check how much time is past from last press Time.time-lastpress> something

void Update()
   {
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Backspace))
       {
           ProcessBackspace();
       }
   }

it will trigger only once for every keypress,
problem lies else where.
1->check if you have attached this script to multiple objects.

Thank you!                                          My Problem was that every chess piece on the board detected the keypress and all of them (32) executed the code.

Try this.
This give you a way to display the count down in seconds in the UI.
void Update()
  {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Backspace))
    {
        ProcessBackspace();
    }
  }

IEnumerator ProcessBackspace()
{

  for ( int i = 0; i < cooldown; i++; ) {
yield new WaitForSeconds(1);
if (chessBoard.AllGamesMoves.Count > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Activated");
        // my code ...
        
    }
 }
 }


I refactored your code to run in a coroutine and provide a way to track the time your delaying. Why the downvote?
